# NgSubmit isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a web app with Laravel as backend and AngularJS for frontend. This is my first time in AngularJS. Here's my code

**login.php**

```
<html ng-app="Liquor">
<!--head-->
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="center-block row">
        <div ng-controller="LoginController">
            <form novalidate name="LoginForm" ng-submit="attempt()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="username" name="username" class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="User Name" autofocus="true"/>
                    <input type="password" ng-required="true" name="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="Password"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" ng-model="rememberme" />
                    <small>Remember me</small>
                    <br/>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var Liquor = angular.module('Liquor',[]);
```

**LoginController.js**

```
Liquor.controller('LoginController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.attempt = function(){
        alert('test');
    }
}]);
```

Comment: [Looks like it works to me](http://plnkr.co/edit/PHVhYGmyH7hzlMViNIVT?p=preview)

Comment: make sure you dob't have any other JS errors and your files are properly included

Comment: I'm getting uncaught object in angularjs file in chrome console! I'm using google cdn so I think something's wrong in my side.